# Manipulating Java string containing math operands

Tags: java, string, operators

Manipulating Java string containing math operands.

I am amending a code for control signals. I have to convert this sort of strings:

```
String str=    "Red 0.20 + 0.60 Green 0.30 + 0.45 + 0.56 Blue 0.25 + 0.50 + 1.0 Yellow 3.0/2.0 ";
```

to this:

```
String str1= "RedNet0.8 GreenNet0.75   BlueNet1.75 YellowNet1.5 ";
```

I can replace Red to RedNet, Green to GreenNet etc., but help me to proceed for remaining part.

Comment: `String[] str1 = str.split(" ")` After you know that in some position you have operators, in others the values etc. Loop through the array str1 and parse all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for a solution:

```
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
int index = 0;

while(index < tokens.length) {
    String colorName = tokens[index++];
    Decimal colorValue = parseNumber(tokens[index++]); // Use some appropriate decimal datatype here

    while(true) {
        String operator = tokens[index];
        if (operator is neither "+", "-" nor any of the other operators) {
            break;
        }
        index++;
        switch(tokens[index++]) {
            case "+":
                colorValue += parseNumber(tokens[index++]);
                break;
            case "-":
                colorValue -= parseNumber(tokens[index++]);
                break;
            ... and so on for all operators ...
        }
    }

    output colorName + "Net" + colorValue + " ";
}
```